# How to set click event for notification Windows 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1

I am new to Windows development and I have created a Windows 8.1 application using C# and xaml on Visual Studio. I have created a toast message.

```
var template = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);
var element = template.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0];
element.AppendChild(template.CreateTextNode("INR BUDDY"));
var element1 = template.GetElementsByTagName("text")[1];
element1.AppendChild(template.CreateTextNode("You have a message!"));
//set the toast to appear 30 seconds from now
var date = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(1);
var stn = new ScheduledToastNotification(template, date);
notifier.AddToSchedule(stn);
IXmlNode toastNode = template.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
```

But I want my user to be transferred to a specific page with this line of code when they click the notification.

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(HomeScreenV2));
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When your toast notification is clicked the OnLaunched event is fired and any parameters you have added to your notification will be in the `Arguments` property

App.cs

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
   //parameters from Toast
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Arguments))
   {
       string arguments= e.Arguments;

       if (arguments == "Whatever")
       {
           this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(HomeScreenV2));
       }
    }    
}
```

**Note**  If you do not include a launch attribute string in your toast and your app is already running when the toast is selected, the OnLaunched event is not fired.

More can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868212.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the help. You have to bare with me I am new to this. Including this line of code:((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", "{\"type\":\"toast\",\"param1\":\"12345\",\"param2: links my toast to the OnLaunched, like a click event in xaml does. But why do you check if argument == whatever in the if statement. What does whatever represent

Comment: its just a hypothetical parameter check. Sorry for confusion just leave it out in your app its not needed :)