# How to make a ToastNotification's Button do things

Tags: c#, winforms, toast, windows-community-toolkit

**Intro:** I am writing a Windows form application that sends Windows toast notifications.
*I can send toast notifications (with buttons) without problems, as well as do things when the notification is activated* using `toast.Activated += ToastActivated;`

**Problem:** I can't figure out how to receive information from the button on the toast notification when it is clicked and use that to do things.

**What I have so far:** I have the code necessary to create a toast with a button and set its activation type and arguments.

```
    /**
     * Constructs the XML necessary for a toast to have a button
     */
    private static XmlDocument constructToastButton(string button)
    {
        ToastActionsCustom actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
        {
            Buttons =
            {
                new ToastButton(button, "contact")
                {
                    ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Foreground,
                }
            }
        };

        ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent()
        {
            Actions = actions,
        };

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(toastContent.GetContent());
        return doc;
    }
```

**Some of the Things I've looked at:**

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653304/toast-notification-response-in-background-task) was really helpful but it's aimed at someone using a Windows Universal Platform project. I don't think I can override the Application.OnActivated method in a desktop application and for the life of me I cannot get my project to recognize `ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs` even when adding `using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;`
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758405/project-targeting-net-framework-version-4-5-1-to-universal-windows-10) on mixing desktop and UWP applications
- [ToastButton class](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp-community-toolkit/api/microsoft_toolkit_uwp_notifications_toastbutton)
- [ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.toastnotificationactivatedeventargs)

Comment: \Your toast notification includes a button. I can't see a click event attached to it. Did you try doing that?

Comment: @Nobody I'm not sure what you mean - I do catch when the toast is clicked-on using `toast.Activated += ToastActivated;` but the button is created using xml - I don't know how to create a click event that will pick up the information returned by the user clicking the button. Note: toast.Activated is part of the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications Api.

Comment: Okay. Refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868212.aspx) . You can apparently use `OnLaunched` event for that. I hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29205638) might help you further

Comment: @Nobody Thank you, but I don't think I explained that well. I can successfully do things when the toast is clicked, it's the buttons that I'm having problems with. Right now if the user clicks the toast a webpage opens in their default browser but my buttons do nothing.

Comment: Truth to be told I haven't used Toolkit and Toast Notification yet. But if `ToastButton` has properties and events of a `Button`, you can add this  to its code block `Click += ToastBtn_Click;` and then `ToastBtn_Click` use this event as per your requirement

Comment: @Nobody It only has Activated, Dismissed and Failed, which is understandable since you can have multiple buttons. That's the reason I've been having trouble. The buttons return an argument as a string (`"contact"` in the above code). I'm hoping `ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs` isn't the only way to get that event because it seems like you can only use it if you have a UWP app.